# Install labelme annotation tools

Tags: python, machine-learning, pyqt, computer-vision, label

I tried to install `labelme` annotation tools on Mac os 10.11.x from this link [labelme](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/labelme/2.8.0) using the virtual environment method listed below:

```
# python3
conda create --name=labelme python=3.6
source activate labelme
# conda install pyqt
pip3 install pyqt5 # pyqt5 can be installed via pip on python3
pip3 install labelme
```

When I run labelme on terminal I get this error:

```
File "/Users/xxx/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/labelme/app.py", line 32, in <module>

from PyQt5.QtGui import *

ImportError: dlopen(/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/PyQt5/QtGui.so, 2): 
Symbol not found: _PyInt_AsLong

Referenced from: /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/PyQt5/QtGui.so
Expected in: flat namespace in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/PyQt5/QtGui.so
```

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/Users/xxxx/anaconda3/bin/labelme", line 7, in <module>
from labelme.app import main
File "/Users/rafikgouiaa/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/labelme/app.py", line 37, in <module>

from PyQt4.QtGui import *
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'PyQt4'**
```

It seems that `labelme` looks for `pyqt5` in Python 2.7, not in Python 3.6 where `pyqt5` is installed.

Any help for installing labelme or any other tools other than labelme and Matlab tools?

Comment: temporarly rename your python 2.7 folder `usr/local/lib/python2.7` and retry. Its probably just taking the first found python refference from the PATH-variable - just a guess